# Amazon MWS Connection String Not Working

Tags: amazon-mws

The connection string below is returning an 'Invalid Address' error. The error message indicates that the API Version is missing, but it is included in the string (see the last parameter). Not sure what the issue is.

https://mws.amazonservices.com/AWSAccessKeyId=[ID Hidden]&Action=GetFeedSubmissionList
&Marketplace=ATVPDKIKX0DER&Merchant=[Merchant Hidden]&Signature=[Signature Hidden]
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2013-10-17T00:37:34.100Z&Version=2009-01-01

Answer (score 0):

I usually send my MWS calls through a HTTP POST command, because that's the only way to do a `SubmitFeed`. The following assumes that a GET works at all (I didn't test):

Your call is missing the `?` separator between the query and the rest of the URL. So as a minimum, this should read:

`https://mws.amazonservices.com/?AWSAccessKeyId....`